# execution order of tasks and methods in gradle

Tags: gradle

I am bit confused about the execution order of tasks and methods in gradle file.
I have below gradle script

```
task Hello {
  doFirst{
    println "Hello First"

      if(sayHello()) {
        tasks['World'].execute()    
      }
  }
  doLast{
      println "Hello Last"
  }
}

task World {
  doFirst{
      println "World First"
  }
  doLast{
      println "World Last"
  }
}

def sayHello(){
  println "Hello from sayHello"
  return false
}
```

When I run `gradle Hello` on command line it shows below output -

```
C:\> gradle Hello

> Task :Hello
Hello First
Hello from sayHello
Hello Last
```

This was expected as sayHello() method returns false and it did not execute the World task.

I have confusion when sayHello() method returns true. Output -

```
C:\> gradle Hello         

> Task :World          
World First            
World Last             

> Task :Hello          
Hello First            
Hello from sayHello    
Hello Last
```

but I was expecting something like this -

```
C:\> gradle Hello       

> Task :Hello        
Hello First
Hello from sayHello

> Task :World        
World First          
World Last

Hello Last
```

Another thing I read was we should not use execute on tasks.

What are other ways in which we can implement similar logic without using execute on task?

I read about dependsOn but can we add condition on dependsOn so that it would be executed when some flag is true/false?

I want to extract the logic checking part to method as it would be used at many places and I don't want to write the same logic in every task again and again.

Is it okay to call methods from gradle tasks or its not recommended? If not, what could be other ways to achieve the same ?

Comment: *can we add condition on dependsOn*: yes. It's a method. You can call this method from inside an if block if you want to. *what could be other ways to achieve the same ?* the same as what? You posted an unrealistic example. If you ant the best solution for your actual problem, then describe what your actual problem is.

Comment: @JBNizet I want to execute another task from one task based on some conditional logic. That logic I am trying to encapsulate in method. But I read we should not call execute on tasks like in my example. More appropriate approach I found was dependsOn.. but did not know we can provide condition for dependsOn.